# Swift-Put Differing Types of UI Elements in an array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make an array of UI elements, but with different types inside. Some are image views, and some are buttons. I am familiar with making a collection of the same type, such as

```
@IBOutlet var things: [UIButton]!
```

but that code only makes an array of buttons, while I need to add image views to that also. How can I make an array that accepts both types?

Comment: Note that this can't be an `IBOutlet`. Do you mean to mark it `IBOutletCollection`, or did you add that by accident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!

var uiElements:[UIView] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button1 = UIButton()
    let image1 = UIImageView()

    uiElements.append(button1)
    uiElements.append(image1)
    uiElements.append(view2)

    for element in uiElements {

        if element is UIButton {
            print("it's a button")
        } else if element is UIImageView {
            print("it's imageview")
        } else if element is UIView {
            print("it's uiview")
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
 }

Output:
it's a button
it's imageview
it's uiview
```

Comment: Why use `AnyObject`? Use `UIView` since it is an array of views.

Answer (score 3):

Just use array of UIViews. `var arrayOfThings : [UIView]`